# cross domain can be set but unable to retrieve value

Tags: javascript, java, cookies

I have a service that sets a cookie to disable popups from a page. I have set a domain for this cookie and it should be available to this domain. However, when I call the page from a subdomain the java did not pick up the cookie value and instead popup was still shown.

ie.

```
http://www.example.com/landing
landing page (cookie is empty - popup was shown) -> calls java backend to set cookie (pop-up)

cookie - {name: 'pop' value: 'n' }
domain - example.com

http://www.abc.example.com/
page with subdomain (I can see the cookie) 
cookie - {name: 'pop' value: 'n' }
domain - example.com

-> make ajax call from http://www.abc.example.com/ to http://www.example.com/landing
cookie - {name: 'pop' value: 'n' }
domain - example.com
```

Now, When I tried to land on the http://www.example.com/landing I saw the pop up still being shown.
Even the cookie was set to 'n' From the log I see the value reading from cookie is null. Why does this happen??

Java backend -

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/landing", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Object getPopup(@RequestBody PopRequest req, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
    ....
     String popup = getCookie(request, "pop");
     // this popup is null
    ... 


}
    public String getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
        String value = "";
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    jwt = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Note that I can see the cookie from the browser but when the call was made I see the cookie was null from the getCookie.

Answer (score 0):

In the backend code, I can see that you are initializing value to empty string and cookie value is assigned to jwt variable. So, finally reponse(value) returns null.

```
public String getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
        String value = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    value = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```